# Is there a command on CMake to started executable resulted from build?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to write generic way to run executable resulted after build using *CMake*'s way.

```
git clone git@github.com:gargamel/ihatesmurfs.git

cmake -E make_directory build
cmake -Sihatesmurfs -Bbuild
cmake --build build
cmake -E chdir build
```

Now I want to start executable but on *nix, it's like:

```
./output
```

and on Windows:

```
output.exe
```

Is there a way to escape this with any possible CMake command?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` files for the project? If so, CMake's `add_custom_command` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!! I will definitely check that command out...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment a bit, you can modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the project to include `add_custom_command`. If your CMake creates an executable named `HateSmurfs`, you can add the custom command to run the executable after compilation completes:

```
add_executable(HateSmurfs smurfs.cpp)

# Add this piece of code to run the executable after it is built.
add_custom_command(
    TARGET HateSmurfs
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND HateSmurfs
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) documentation:

> `COMMAND`
>     If `COMMAND` specifies an executable target name (created by the `add_executable()` command) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time.